# asyncio run_until_complete blocks after future has set result (autobahn websockets & threading)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, autobahn

**TL;DR:** Calling `future.set_result` doesn't immediately resolve `loop.run_until_complete`. Instead it blocks for an additional 5 seconds.

**Full context:**
In my project, I'm using [autobahn](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python) and asyncio to send and receive messages with a websocket server. For my use case, I need a 2nd thread for websocket communication, since I have arbitrary blocking code that will be running in the main thread. The main thread also needs to be able to schedule messages for the communication thread to send back and forth with the server. My current goal is to send a message originating from the main thread and block until the response comes back, using the communication thread for all message passing.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import asyncio
import threading
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory, WebSocketClientProtocol


CLIENT = None


class MyWebSocketClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    # -------------- Boilerplate --------------
    is_connected = False
    msg_queue = []
    msg_listeners = []

    def onOpen(self):
        self.is_connected = True

        for msg in self.msg_queue[::]:
            self.publish(msg)

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        is_connected = False

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        for listener in self.msg_listeners:
            listener(payload)

    def publish(self, msg):
        if not self.is_connected:
            self.msg_queue.append(msg)
        else:
            self.sendMessage(msg.encode('utf-8'))
    # /----------------------------------------

    def send_and_wait(self):
        future = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()

        def listener(msg):
            print('set result')
            future.set_result(123)

        self.msg_listeners.append(listener)
        self.publish('hello')

        return future


def worker(loop, ready):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    factory = WebSocketClientFactory('ws://127.0.0.1:9000')
    factory.protocol = MyWebSocketClientProtocol
    transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_connection(factory, '127.0.0.1', 9000))

    global CLIENT
    CLIENT = protocol
    ready.set()

    loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set up communication thread to talk to the server
    threaded_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    thread_is_ready = threading.Event()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(threaded_loop, thread_is_ready))
    thread.start()
    thread_is_ready.wait()

    # Send a message and wait for response
    print('starting')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(CLIENT.send_and_wait())
    print('done') # this line gets called 5 seconds after it should
```

- I'm using the [autobahn echo server example](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/asyncio/websocket/echo/server.py) to respond to my messages.

**Problem:** The WebSocketClientProtocol receives the response to its outgoing message and calls `set_result` on its pending future, but `loop.run_until_complete` blocks an additional ~4.9 seconds until eventually resolving.

I understand that `run_until_complete` also processes other pending events on the event loop. Is it possible that the main thread has somehow queued up a bunch of events that have to now get processed once I start the loop? Also, if I move `run_until_complete` into the communications thread or move the `create_connection` into the main thread, then the event loop doesn't block me.

Lastly, I tried to recreate this problem without using autobahn, but I couldn't cause the extra delay. I'm curious if maybe this is an issue with the nature of autobahn's callback timing (`onMessage` for example).

Comment: Is `onMessage` invoked in the same thread as the one that runs the event loop? (Print out `threading.current_thread()` if you are not sure.) Does it help if you replace `future.set_result(123)` with `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(future.set_result, 123)` where the `loop` variable is set in the *outer function* (the same one that sets the `future` variable)?

Comment: `onMessage` is invoked from the worker thread that is handling the communications, not the main thread. It does help if I make the change that you suggested. This must be because the `listener` function inside of `send_and_wait` is being called from the worker thread when `onMessage` is fired (which as determined before is being invoked from the worker thread). Therefore, we need to use a threadsafe call soon in order to set the result of the future that was created in the main thread's event loop outside of the `listener` function.

Comment: This solution will work, but since autobahn supports asyncio, you probably don't need multiple event loops or multiple threads to begin with. Asyncio is really good at allowing unrelated tasks to share an event loop, and you can have multiple client connections in one. Using asyncio your `worker` would be `async def` and instead of using `run_until_complete`, it would simply `await` the call to `create_connection`. Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/abR4U87y).